# css borders in chrome too thick

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a problem that happens only in Google Chrome. The borders appear to be "too thick". In Firefox, everything seems normal (I've tested in chrome and firefox only so far).

As you can see on the image, there are 2 problems:

1) upper arrow: the borders are to thick (it is 1px solid #aaa). When I draw a table with css, the borders are normal. This happens only with div's and form input fields.

2) lower arrow: the background of the inner div slightly goes above the border of the outer div.

[image]

Could this be a bug in Chrome?

```
.outer-div{
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer-div > .inner-div{
    padding: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(#eee,#ddd);
}
```

EDIT: the code that produces the results where the lower arrow is pointing at.

```
.calendar-events-block{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin: 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.calendar-events-block > .events{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.calendar-events-block > .events > .title{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: linear-gradient(#eee,#ddd);
}
```

EDIT 2: If I zoom out to 90%, everything seems normal (like in Firefox).

EDIT 3: a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/p31ajt48/) with the problem.

EDIT 4: Funny detail: when I zoom in or out, the problem with the "overflow" (the background of the title that goes over the border) dissapears.

Another screenshot:

[image]

Left you have a table, at the right you have some divs. The border of the table = 1px solid #aaa, the border of the divs = 1px solid #aaa, but the tabel borders are much thinner than the div borders.

Comment: it's seems a overlow issue, so the inner element is above the border I think, can yo share a code that produce the issue?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Oh, your username: "[modified 2 mins ago yesterday](https://imgur.com/a/QhOBiwD)."

Comment: @DavidThomas lol :p you thought a moment about a system bug? :p

Comment: @yesterday we need the complete code with html .. today :p

Comment: @Temani: not so much a bug, but there was a brief "wait, what..?" moment. :D

Comment: I added a jsfiddle to my question.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Have you every found a solution to this? The accepted answer doesn't work work me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is only happening in chrome, It's probably got to do with chrome's default styling. Try adding a css reset to the document or try adding

```
* {
border: none;
}
```

to your body.

Comment: I added a css reset (https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and I set * { border: none; } but the borders stay the same.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle to my question.