# Chrome issue in rendering 1 pixel width table row border CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

Although there are many threads— such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181143/css-borders-in-chrome-too-thick)— related to Chrome's seemingly problematic rendering of table/border-related CSS, I have not found a post that describes the (maddening) issue I've encountered with the inconsistent rendering of a 1 pixel border applied to the `<tr>` element in a table. If you look at the simple example below in which I apply `border-bottom: 1px solid #000` to the `<tr>` element (within `tbody`), you'll see that Chrome seems to apply a thicker border to the first, third and fifth rows. However, if I change the border width to `0.5px` or even `2px`, the borders are all rendered consistently. This issue does not occur in Firefox- is this simply a bug in Chrome and if so, is there any kind of workaround other than changing the width from 1 pixel? In case the embedded example below doesn't demonstrate the issue, I've also created a CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/nickpish/pen/ZExmmmz).

*Edit: I should note that I'm on Windows (11) on a 4k monitor w/ scaling set in display settings- so it's possible it could be OS-related (?)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
thead th {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
tbody td {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
    <th>Heading 4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thead is being applied a 2px border, literally. Change it to 1px, does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Niloct I'm referring to the `<tr>` elements within `<tbody>` - the 2px bottom border for `thead` is just meant to differentiate the header row from the table body. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, can you go to your system preferences and search for the zoom level of the OS? Try to set it back to 100%.

Comment: @Kaiido I am indeed on Windows- are you not seeing the difference in border width on your screen? I was wondering if this might be display/scaling-related...

Comment: On my macOS I can only see it when I manually zoom the page to 125%, but IIRC Windows does set the zoom to 125% by default, at the OS level. It would be great if you could check that changing this setting fixes the issue for you. This way we could confirm that what you experience is indeed antialiasing artifacts and we could try to find a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Kaiido - that's interesting. I'm viewing on a 4k display on Windows 11 w/ scaling set to 150% - although, I have a second monitor w/ different scaling set and the same issue occurs on both displays.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the odd 2px lines by removing the padding and setting height instead. I hope it helps!

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  border-spacing:0;
    thead { 
        border-bottom: 0.9px solid #000;
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
            /*padding: 20px 0;*/
            height:20px;
        }
    }
    tbody {
        td {
            /*padding: 20px 0;*/
            height: 40px;
        }
        tr { height:20px;
            border-bottom: 0.9px solid #000;
        }
    }
}
```

[print of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVAsj.png)

Comment: Hm, I'm seeing you also changed the border width to 0.9px - is that required as well, or does just setting the height and removing the padding alone fix the issue for you? I'm not getting the same result on my end.

Comment: It was two things, removing the paddings and adding the heights. I forgot the border widths in 0.9px but it might work as 1px as well. For some reason the table was acting weird with the paddings.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue so many times and as you want i have solved this without changing the border width. Please check below code -

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  display: block;
}
thead tr {
  display: block;
}
thead th {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: left;
}
tbody td {
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
}
tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
}
```

Like you can see above css code. I have added display:block; property where you have border property. Without display property table border css doesn't work properly. There are other css which i have added so that ui look fine.